# Why can't Perl's Class::XSAccessor find Array.so?

Tags: perl

This is my first post and I am hoping someone can point me in the right direction.  I have tried Google but am not coming up with anything;  actually, there are hardly getting any hits so I assume this is going to be a pretty obscure error.

I am trying to run a perl application (squeezecenter-7.3.3) on Solaris 10 and get the following error:

> "ld.so.1: perl: fatal: relocation error: file /opt/squeezecenter-7.3.3/CPAN/arch/5.10.0/i86pc-solaris/auto/Class/XSAccessor/Array/Array.so: symbol get_next_arrayindex: referenced symbol not found"

ld.so.1 is in the search path, but I can't figure out what—ld.so.1 or Array.so—is causing the error.  Any help will be appreciated.

Thanks

Comment: What's the output of "perl -V"? Perhaps you're using a different perl version (5.8.x or something).

Answer (score 7):

**LATE UPDATE 2009-12-04**

The current version of Class::XSAccessor contains both Class::XSAccessor itself and Class::XSAccessor::Array. It does not use AutoXS.pm to generate AutoXS.h any more but ships a static copy. Therefore, the problem giving rise to the question shouldn't occur (ever) again.

---

While Chris Simmons' idea is a good one, this is most certainly not the problem you're having. It is most likely an incompatibility between the version of [Class::XSAccessor::Array](http://search.cpan.org/dist/Class-XSAccessor-Array) you're using and the [AutoXS::Header](http://search.cpan.org/dist/AutoXS-Header) version it was compiled with.

A practically guaranteed* fix would be to reinstall Class::XSAccessor from CPAN. It should pick up a compatible version of AutoXS::Header. Maybe you should also post on the SlimDevices/Logitech forum about this.

On a more general note, as the author of both modules in question, I'm not sure *why* this problem is occurring at all. The dependency on version 1.02 of AutoXS::Header is part of the most recent Class::XSAccessor::Array release. Therefore, if dependencies are met correctly, everything should be fine. It may be some peculiarity of how the SqueezeCenter folks update their bundled modules. If not, feel free to get them in touch with me.

*The one problem remaining may be that the Class::XSAccessor::Array that comes with SqueezeCenter is prefered over the one you installed from CPAN (potentially into the system). In that case, you can try to install it into your /opt/squeezecenter.../CPAN directory.

Comment: Thanks for the quick response.  I will also post it on the SlimDevices/Logitech forum, but initially I was not sure if this was purely a squeezecenter issue due to the error message.

Comment: Please don't get me wrong. I don't want to be finger-pointing. It's not necessarily purely a SqeezeCenter issue. It does look like it is to me, but if it turns out it's not, I'll be more than happy to work with whomever to fix it.

Comment: Oh, I definitely did not take it the wrong way!  To be honest, I just did not know where to start looking as I did not know if the problem was with ld.so.1 or perl modules or neither one.  I am not that familier with compiling and linking etc.

Answer (score 4):

Reinstall the offending module.  Run this as root:

```
cpan -i Class::XSAccessor::Array Class::XSAccessor
```

Or manually install [it](http://search.cpan.org/dist/Class-XSAccessor-Array/).

Comment: Please link to the module in a version-agnostic way. Either to the distribution via http://search.cpan.org/dist/Class-XSAccessor-Array or via http://search.cpan.org/perldoc?Class::XSAccessor::Array. The link to version 1.04 will go bad when I release newer versions and clean up my CPAN directory.

Comment: Done. Though, to be fair, most people would have used the cpan command.

Comment: There's no need for the extra typing in that command. Without any switches, cpan(1) assumes the -i switch. :)